# Websocket connection returns 404 when pc is connected to VPN

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, vpn

I have a pet project that I use every day. Everything works fine. Today I tried to connect to my app from **working machine which uses VPN**. And I realized that websocket connection returns 404 on that machine. At the same time all other calls work and if VPN is disabled websocket connects. What can be wrong? Below I provide some technical details:

1) My application uses https protocol only.

2) I host app on VPS server which uses nginx as a reverse proxy.

3) I have enabled HSTS

4) Backend is using nodejs.

5) Request/response headers

**Request**

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host: www.myhost here.com
Origin:https://www.myhost here.com
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:uFGdO7ucgpERSD6JgwCChg==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

**Response**

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 29 Sep 2017 10:55:06 GMT
ETag:W/"c29-/gW6vwdzLmRRt7uhZazoend/0b0"
Server:nginx
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

Comment: Nginx logs when the 404 occurs? Also anything in NodeJS logs that time?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Logs are clean. It means that my general nodeJS handler returns that 404.